# Правильным ли является такой код?

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода

```
var btnReady = document.getElementById('ready');

btnReady.addEventListener('click', function() {
  pasteText(h2, sayPhrase[0]);
  changeCss(h2, 'color', '#000');
  changeCss(lampImg1, 'display', 'none');
  changeCss(btnRepeat, 'cursor', 'default');
  changeCss(lampImg2, 'display', 'block');
  changeCss(dontClick, 'display', 'none');
  changeCss(btnReady, 'display', 'none');
  changeCss(btnRepeat, 'display', 'block');
  play('audio/LightSwitch.mp3');
  changeCss(rightBlock, 'backgroundColor', "#000");
  changeCss(leftBlock, 'backgroundColor',"#fff");
  changeCss(rightBlock, 'backgroundImage', "url(img/troll.png)");
  setAnimate(lampImg2, 'animated swing');
}, false);

function changeCss(node, selector, property) {
  node.style[selector] = property;
}
```

Comment: А почему нет? `changeCss` ваша функция?

Comment: Да да это функция

Comment: Просто слишком массивно смотрится ))

Comment: Вы написали эту функцию или вставили от куда-то?

Comment: Я писал эту функцию

Comment: Можете её тоже выложить, я примерно знаю, как можно её сократить

Comment: changeCss(); - выложить?

Comment: О, хорошо, сейчас чуть попробуем сократить

Comment: @DenisoDeniso, я сегодня буду готов пообщаться по поводу вашего кода, если будет время зайдите в общий чат (http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--) и пинганите меня оттуда написав мой ник через собачку, дальше в чатах и поговорим

Answer (score 1):

У вас всё нормально, но я бы функцию `changeCss` переделал бы в такую:

```js
var btnReady = document.getElementById('ready');

btnReady.addEventListener('click', function(){
  changeCss(btnReady, {'background-color': 'red', 'color': 'white', 'border': '0'})
}, false);

function changeCss(obj, styles) {
  for(key in styles){
    obj.style[key] = styles[key];
  };
};
```

```html
<button id="ready">Клик</button>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51314/discussion-on-answer-by-yuri-----).